# Make vertical line colorcolumn thinner?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I set a vertical line with `setlocal colorcolumn`, is there a way to make it thinner? Or a workaround? I already have a function to color long lines but I prefer to have a thin vertical line. I changed the color so it won't be so obvious

Comment: You will not have much success with `colorcolumn` as all it does it to apply a highlighting group to a specific column so the whole column will always be shown. If you use neovim, maybe there is something to do with [`:h nvim_buf_set_virtual_text()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_buf_set_virtual_text%28%29) I think that's how [this plugin](https://github.com/lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim) does to show the indent line character (but I'm not 100% sure it's possible as the doc says that the virtual text is always shown after the actual text)